# perfect match graph theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, matching-theory

The question:

> Prove that if $G$ is a graph with $2n$ vertices and degree of each
>   one is at least $n$, then  there is perfect match in G.

hint???

Comment: What is perfect match?

Comment: @hyprfrco [Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Definition)

Comment: Hint: You can use Hall's theorem to prove there is a perfect matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prove each step in sequence or use previous results from your book/lecture notes

Step 1:

- A graph with $2n$ vertices where every degree is at least $n$ must be connected

Step 2:

- A graph with $2n$ vertices where every degree is at least $n$ must have a Hamiltonian cycle.

Step 3: (*hidden with spoiler tag*)

> - A graph with a Hamiltonian cycle and an even number of vertices must have a perfect matching.